# Listed twice in the weekly reputation

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I (Slarty) appear to have two entries in the weekly reputation score listing

[image]

Comment: See the background? It's different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's by design. It will show you, and your position on top (so you can see it even when your position is less awesome than it is now), as well as in terms of the overall standings on weekly, monthly and quarterly.

Yearly doesn't for some reason but otherwise, this is by design

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now I should have looked further around. On a related  point what happens to any reputation above 200 points / day is it simply lost?

Comment: *Sometimes - its a wee bit complex but bounties and accepts still count past 200.